# Vue Component not Re-rendered after Ajax Call Laravel Mix

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, laravel-mix

I have a hotel site that uses AJAX to retrieve data. The data is displayed using card view. Some parts of the card are using the Vue component (Favorite Button and Currency Select).

[image: card view]

So, on the first load, all of the hotel cards load properly (including the favorite and currency select). Then after the second scroll, the favorite and currency select option is loaded, but not re-rendered.

[image: favorite button not showing]

[image: favorite button on inspect element]

I'm using :

- Jquery JScroll

```js
$('ul.pagination').hide();
        $(function() {
            $('.scrolling-pagination').jscroll({
                autoTrigger: true,
                padding: 0,
                nextSelector: '.pagination li.active + li a',
                contentSelector: 'div.scrolling-pagination',
                loadingHtml: '',
                callback: function() {
                    $('ul.pagination').remove();
                }
            });
        });
```

- layout.blade (call the compiled vue file)

```html
    <script src="{{ mix('js/guest-app.min.js') }}" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

- card.blade

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#map-area" class="property-map-icon"><i class="fa fa-map-o fa-lg" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href="#" class="email-btn property-email property-email-contact-agent" id="property-email-contact-agent-{{ $slugPropertyId }}"></i></a></li>
    <li><fav-button
        property-id="{{ $property->property_id }}"
        slug-property-id="{{ $slugPropertyId }}"
        @add="addFav"
        @remove="removeFav"
    ></fav-button></li>
</ul>
```